# Is it possible to use multicolumn and multirow simultaneously in a single cell?

Tags: latex, tex

I'm trying to draw a table, but I faced a problem with the extra column line.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,tabu}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{A. \label{table8}}
\centering
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{B}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{C} \\
    \cline{4-7}
     & &  & E & F & G & H \\
    \cline{1-7} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{D} &
    \multirow{3}{*}{K}  & $1.0612e-09$ & $1.0610e-09$ &  $5.2760e-10$ &  $3.7844e-08$ & $7.6545e-06 $\\
    \cline{3-7} 
    &  & $9.724e-10$ & $9.7239e-10$ &  $4.8758e-10$ &  $4.9127e-08$ & $7.7153e-06 $\\
    \cline{3-7} 
    & & $9.132e-10$ & $9.131e-10$ &  $4.1633e-10$ &  $4.3932e-08$ & $8.2672e-06$\\[-1pt]
    %\cline{2-7
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table*}
```

Does anyone know how to remove this extra line that shown in

[image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `tabu` package - it is more or less completely broken. The only thing which helds this package together is a lot of [ducktape](https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu) by the latex team.

Instead you could use `tabularray` package, which makes merging cells much easier and you'll also don't have to worry how long all your lines should be.

You might also want to choose another column type, like S from siunitx, to avoid the incorrect spacing around your minus signs ....

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{A. \label{table8}}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
colspec={|c|c|S[table-format=1.3e-2]|S[table-format=1.3e-2]|S[table-format=1.3e-2]|S[table-format=1.3e-2]|S[table-format=1.3e-2]|},
vlines,
hlines,
row{1-2} = {guard}
}
    \SetCell[r=2]{} A & \SetCell[c=2,r=2]{} B && \SetCell[c=4]{} C &&& \\
     & &  & E & F & G & H \\
    \SetCell[r=3]{} D &
    \SetCell[r=3]{} K  & 1.0612e-09 & 1.0610e-09 & 5.2760e-10 &  3.7844e-08 & 7.6545e-06\\
    &  & 9.724e-10 & 9.7239e-10 & 4.8758e-10 & 4.9127e-08 & 7.7153e-06\\
    & & 9.132e-10 & 9.131e-10 & 4.1633e-10 & 4.3932e-08 & 8.2672e-06\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

[image]